# How to import modules given a list of their names?

Tags: python, list, import, module

I am trying to import modules from a list. This would be to allow easier editing of imported modules, cleaner error message, and better error handling. Here is basically what I am trying to do:

```
imports = ['sys', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'os']
for x in imports:
    try:
        import x
        print "Successfully imported ", x, '.'
    except ImportError:
        print "Error importing ", x, '.'
```

The issue here is that it tries importing x, not the value x should hold. I realize that to import from the list I could do something like below, but I do not see a way to handle the errors with it:

```
imports = ['sys', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'os']
modules = map(__import__, imports)
```

Is there a way to integrate the error handling with this method or should I try a different approach?

Comment: you have the solution already, in your `map` you are passing the right function : `__import__`. Just use `__import__(x)` in your `try` block

Comment: *"... allow easier editing of imported modules, cleaner error message, and better error handling"* - actually, quite the opposite is true. This will prevent any static code analysis tool like `PyFlakes` from warning you about missing or unused imports, make sorting and editing imports harder, and obfuscate / hide error messages.

Comment: Other than testing for optional functionality, import errors either point to a Python installation problem or something that should be caught during testing; in neither case should you bother checking at run time for such errors.

Comment: Perhaps the print function in the except was a little misleading. The purpose of the error checking is to then install needed modules if they fail on startup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of mapping them to `___import__` all at once, just append each module to the list `modules` one at a time inside the for-loop:

```
imports = ['sys', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'os']
modules = []
for x in imports:
    try:
        modules.append(__import__(x))
        print "Successfully imported ", x, '.'
    except ImportError:
        print "Error importing ", x, '.'
```

Note however that most Python programmers prefer the use of [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) rather than `__import__` for this task.

---

Note too that it might be better to make `modules` a dictionary instead of a list:

```
imports = ['sys', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'os']
modules = {}
for x in imports:
    try:
        modules[x] = __import__(x)
        print "Successfully imported ", x, '.'
    except ImportError:
        print "Error importing ", x, '.'
```

Now, instead of by index:

```
modules[0].version
modules[3].path
```

you can access the modules by name:

```
modules["sys"].version
modules["os"].path
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The modules aren't recognized when called within the program.

Comment: @Sixwinged - The module objects are stored in the list.  You need to index it if you want to access them.  For example, `modules[0].version` will be `sys.version`.

Comment: @Sixwinged - I used a list because you had one in your post.  It might be better though to use a dictionary where the module names are mapped to their objects.  See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

None of the most voted options worked for me. They seemed to be imported successfully, but I couldn't use them later. In case you experienced the same issue, [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-use-multiple-modules-with-Python-import-Statement) solved it for me.

```
modules = ['sys', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'os']  

for lib in modules:
    globals()[lib] = __import__(lib)
```

PS: I guess they were not added to my global variables before

Answer (score 3):

you can import programatically achieving the same effect as *`import module as module_shortname`* by using *`globals()`*:

```
packages_to_import = [{'name': 'numpy', 'as': 'np'},
                      {'name': 'pandas', 'as': 'pd'}]

for package in packages_to_import:
    package_name = package['name']
    import_as = package.get('as', package_name)

    globals()[import_as] = __import__(package_name)

print(np.version.full_version)
print(pd.__version__)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Python 3.7

```
modules = ["sys","os","platform","random","time","functools"]

for library in modules:
try:
    exec("import {module}".format(module=library))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print(sys.argv)
```

Importing a submodule:

```
modules = ["PyQt5"] # pip install PyQt5
submodules = ["QtCore"]

for library in modules:
    for sublibrary in submodules:
        try:
            exec("from {m} import {s}".format(m=library, s=sublibrary))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
print(dir()) # Includes QtCore
print(dir(QtCore)) # All functions, classes and variables are exactly correct as with "from PyQt5 import QtCore"
```

Importing everything:

```
modules = ["sys","os","platform","random","time","functools"]
for library in modules:
    try:
        exec("from {module} import *".format(module=library))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
print(dir()) # Exactly working as thought
```

Importing a instance or something:

```
modules = ["PyQt5"] # pip install PyQt5
submodules = ["QtCore"]
func = ["QCoreApplication"]
for library in modules:
    for f in func:
        for sublibrary in submodules:
            try:
                exec("from {m}.{s} import {f}".format(m=library, s=sublibrary, f=f)) 
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
print(dir()) # Includes QCoreApplication instance
```

Importing everything from a modules's submodule:

```
modules = ["PyQt5"] # pip install PyQt5
submodules = ["QtCore"]
for library in modules:
    for sublibrary in submodules:
        try:
            exec("from {m}.{s} import *".format(m=library, s=sublibrary)) # Didn't mention f"" strings all the times. But for beginners .format is better.
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
print(dir()) # Includes all PyQt5.QtCore stuff
```

Comment: Using `exec()` is a security hazard and should generally be avoided. It's also usually unnecessary…

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `import x` line to use the [`__import__(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) format

```
imports = ['sys', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'os','doesntexit']
for x in imports:
    try:
        __import__(x)
        print "Success"
    except ImportError:
        print "Error ", x
```

Outputs:

```
Success
Success
Success
Success
Error  doesntexit
```

Comment: You need to somehow save the module object returned by `__import__`.  For example, doing `__import__('os');os` will raise a `NameError` unless you do `os = __import__('os');os`.

Answer (score 0):

## Pesky pseudo submodules

This works with pesky pseudo submodules like `lxml.etree`:

```py
# PyPI imports
import pkg_resources, subprocess, sys

modules   = {'lxml.etree', 'pandas', 'screeninfo'}
required  = {m.split('.')[0] for m in modules}
installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing   = required - installed

if missing:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', *missing])

for module in set.union(required, modules):
    globals()[module] = __import__(module)
```

Tests:

```py
print(pandas.__version__)
print(lxml.etree.LXML_VERSION)
```